# configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing': undefined method `development' for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman

I'm new to rails running Ruby 1.9.2 on an OSX machine and at when I moved to using Thin I get the following error (it's worth mentioning that i've used the gemset on a completely new rails app and it works so I know its something to do with the code or configuration i've written

In terms of the gems I have installed:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'thin'
gem 'pg'
gem 'tire'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'devise'
```

This is the error that I get when running 'rails c'

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing': undefined method `development' for #<My::Application:0x007fa4fd937fe8> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/me/Dropbox/2_Development/rails_projects/my/config/environments/development.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
    from /Users/me/Dropbox/2_Development/rails_projects/my/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/me/Dropbox/2_Development/rails_projects/my/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please help... it's driving me nuts... or point me to how to debug the problem myself

Comment: Probably something wrong in development.rb, line 9

Comment: Is it possible that you used something like "do something if development" without the question mark for "development?"

Comment: Thanks Frederick!, I scanned through all the environment files and found a single character out of place.